# Laguerre polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, generating-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

For  $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, let the Laguerre polynomials $L_n^{(\alpha)}(x)$ be defined as the Taylor coefficients of the function $G(w):=(1-w)^{-\alpha-1} \exp\left(- \frac{xw}{1-w}\right)$.

It follows from Fejér's formula (see Szegő's book, *Orthogonal Polynomials*, AMS 1939, formula 8.22.1) that, for $x>0$,

$$
|L_n^\alpha(x)|\leq C(\alpha,x)  n^{\alpha/2-1/4}.
$$

Is there a direct and simple proof of this inequality? Is there  a readable proof (in some textbook) of  Fejér's theorem?

(Szegő's book is  a bit difficult to follow).